# improper output while printing coloured letter of a word in a wordle game in python

Tags: python, wordle-game, termcolor

```
import random
import sys   
from termcolor import colored

def print_menu():
    print("welcome to wordle !")
    print("type a 5 letter word and hit enter\n")

def read_random_word():
    with open('E:\kartikey\python\programs\wordle\words.txt') as word_database:
        #splitline so every line in the text file gets stored as a diferent array
        #block and since here every line is basically a word so every word gets stored as an individual array.
        words=word_database.read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(words).lower()
print_menu()
play_again=""

while play_again !="quit":  
    word=read_random_word()
    for attempt in range(1,7):
        guess=input().lower()
        for i in range(min(len(guess),5)):
            if guess[i]==word[i]:
                #end="" is used so it doesnt go to a new line after printing the coloured letter
                print(colored(guess[i],'green'), end="")  
            elif guess[i] in word:
                print(colored(guess[i],'yellow'), end="")
            else:
                print(guess[i] , end="")  
        if guess==word:
                print((f"\nyou got the word in {attempt} try"))
                break
        elif attempt==6:
            print(f"sorry the wordle was {word}")
play_again=input("type quit to exit otherwise click enter")
```

the error im getting is:

> ```
> welcome to wordle !
> type a 5 letter word and hit enter
>
> poise
> ?[32mp?[0m?[32mo?[0m?[32mi?[0m?[32ms?[0m?[32me?[0m
> you got the word in 1 try
> ```

When I don't use the colored() function this error is not appearing but gives this issue when using it.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Your code runs perfectly. There are no issues with it.

Comment: Imported colorama and initialised it ,works perfectly now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When i don't use the colored() function this error is not appearing but gives this issue when using it.*

The issue is that what you see are escape sequences used to set the color of a single letter in the terminal output.

*Apparently you use a console/terminal which doesn't support escape sequences or run your code in some other environment which output does not support coloring.*

Your code runs perfectly and colors the hit letters in the output. Well done! Just run it in a console supporting escape sequences and enjoy!

Happy coding :)

[image: CodeIsRunningOK]

Below a version of your code with following changes:

- Reading from text file with words to guess is done only once and not each time next word has to be chosen
- Integer constants are moved out of the inner part of the code and given values at the beginning of script
- There is a class for automated user input, so while playing around with colors it's not necessary to provide any input to see how the user interface looks like
- colored() function is used with explicit parameter names to make it simple to see what goes where
- The script doesn't need to access a file to be run and runs as it is utilizing implemented automated user input

---

```
# wordle.py 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73555383/improper-output-while-printing-coloured-letter-of-a-word-in-a-wordle-game-in-pyt
# requires module 'termcolor' : 
import random
import sys   
from termcolor import colored

# --- wordle game parameter:
WORD_LENGTH      = 5
NO_OF_ATTEMPTS   = 7
#                  ^-- to avoid constants spread within the code 
# --- v-- input/output automation constants
AUTOMATED_INPUT  = True  # False
MAX_NO_OF_ROUNDS = 3 # set to negative value for an unlimited number
WORDS_FROM_FILE  = False # True # False
REVEAL_THE_WORD_TO_GUESS = True
# ---
# v-- automated input text
mlnTextIO_mlnText = """\
green
blues
mouse
quit
quit"""
# v-- words to guess
words = """\
mouse
mouse
mouse""".splitlines()
# --- 
class mlnTextIO():
    def __init__(self, mlnText):
        self.lst_mlnText = mlnText.split('\n')
        self.lineNo = 0
        self.lenText=len(self.lst_mlnText)
    def input(self, promptText='without promptText'):
        # print('\n','input() called:', promptText)
        if promptText == 'without promptText':
            pass
        else:
           print(promptText)
        lineNo = self.lineNo
        self.lineNo += 1
        if promptText == "type quit to exit otherwise click enter":
            if lineNo < self.lenText: 
                if self.lst_mlnText[lineNo] != "quit": 
                    self.lineNo -= 1
                    return '\n'
                else: 
                    return 'quit'
            else: 
                return 'quit'                
            #:if/else
        #:if
        if  lineNo < self.lenText:
            print(  self.lst_mlnText[lineNo])            
            return  self.lst_mlnText[lineNo]        
        else:
            return 'No further automated user input available.'
#:def
if AUTOMATED_INPUT: 
    input = mlnTextIO(mlnTextIO_mlnText).input

def print_menu():
    print(f"  Welcome to wordle !")
    print(f"  Type a {WORD_LENGTH} letter word and hit enter\n")

def get_random_word():
    global WORDS_FROM_FILE, words
    if WORDS_FROM_FILE: 
        with open('words.txt') as word_database:
            # splitline so every line in the text file gets stored as a diferent array
            # block and since here every line is basically a word so every word gets stored as an individual array.
            words=word_database.read().splitlines()
        WORDS_FROM_FILE = False
        # ^-- prevents file operation each time a word is requested
    return random.choice(words).lower()

print_menu()
play_again=""

maxNoOfRounds = MAX_NO_OF_ROUNDS
while play_again !="quit" and maxNoOfRounds > 0:

    if maxNoOfRounds == 0:
        print(colored(text="  Restart the program to play again", color='green', on_color='on_white', attrs=['bold']))
    maxNoOfRounds -= 1    
    
    word=get_random_word()
    if REVEAL_THE_WORD_TO_GUESS: 
        print(f'  Wordle word to guess is: "{word}"') # reveals the word to guess

    for attempt in range( 1, NO_OF_ATTEMPTS):
        guess=input().lower()
        for i in range( min(len(guess), WORD_LENGTH) ):
            if guess[i]==word[i]:
                #end="" is used so it doesnt go to a new line after printing the coloured letter
                print(colored(text=guess[i], color='white' , on_color='on_grey', attrs=['bold']),  end="")  
            elif guess[i] in word:
                print(colored(text=guess[i], color='white' , on_color='on_grey'),                  end="")
            else:
                print(colored(text=guess[i], color='red'   , on_color='on_grey', attrs=['bold']) , end="")  
        print()        
        if guess==word:
            print(f"  You got the word using {colored(text=str(attempt), color='white',on_color='on_grey', attrs=['bold'])} attempts")  
            break
        elif attempt==6:
            print(f"  Sorry, but the wordle was {colored(text=word, color='white',on_color='on_grey', attrs=['bold'])}")
        #if/elif
    #:for attempt
    play_again=input("  Type quit to exit otherwise click enter")
#: while play_again
```

The wordle when run in a console/terminal supporting escape sequences for colors and text layout looks now as follows:

[image]

The meaning of colors in the wordle output is as follows:

- bold highlighted white letters are in the proper position.
- white, not bold highlighted letters mean the letter is in the word to guess
- red bold letters are not in the word to guess

And ... if you want to play it instead of playing around with its code just

- put the words to guess into `words`
- change `REVEAL_THE_WORD_TO_GUESS = True` to `False`
- and `AUTOMATED_INPUT  = True` to `False`

Comment: Yes thank you . I've used sys.stdout for clearing the console with my input and replacing it with the colored word on the same line ,looks and feels way cleaner now !

Comment: Please post your updated nicer code in the question so I can pick it up in my answer and future visitors can profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

> finally sorted the code out ,added sys to clear up the output screen after each input guess and replace it with the coloured output for a cleaner interface.

```
import random
import sys
# to clear the terminal and make the game user friendly
import termcolor
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
from termcolor import colored
init(convert=True)


def print_menu():
    print("welcome to wordle !")
    print("type a 5 letter word and hit enter\n")


def read_random_word():
    with open('E:\kartikey\python\programs\wordle\words.txt') as word_database:

        # splitline so every line in the text file gets stored as a diferent array
        # block and since here every line is basically a word so every word gets stored as an individual array.

        words = word_database.read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(words).lower()


print_menu()
play_again = ""

while play_again != "quit":

    word = read_random_word()

    for attempt in range(1, 7):

        guess = input().lower()

        sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')
        sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')

        for i in range(min(len(guess), 5)):
            if guess[i] == word[i]:

                # end="" is used so it doesnt go to a new line after printing the coloured letter

                print(colored(guess[i], 'green'), end="")
            elif guess[i] in word:
                print(colored(guess[i], 'yellow'), end="")

            else:
                print(guess[i], end="")

        print()

        if guess == word:
            print((f"\nyou got the word in {attempt} tries !"))
            break
        elif attempt == 6:
            print(f"sorry the wordle was {word} :(")
    play_again = input("\ntype quit to exit otherwise click enter")
```

Output:
[colouredoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVocF.png)